# How to bind 2 properties together in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, select, razor-pages

I'm building an application in Razor that supports the QA team in my company. The purpose is to reserve tests (called threads) to be executed by the team members. I'm new to programming and I've reached a problem i can't solve :(

OnGet - i get the list of the tests from the database (with the test names and testersIDs). I also get the list of testers from a different table and use that list to populate the drop-downs in the app (so i display the testers names instead of the testerIDs). It works fine.

OnPost - i would like to update the database when someone changes the drop-down values (either onChange or with a submit button). I've tried two options but neither of them works. I'll paste the code below but lets just assume for now that i have two testers in the DB: Id= 1, Name=Tester1 and Id=2, Name=Tetser2. I also have one test in another table that is assigned to the tester of Id=1. I want to change it to Id=2.

The model:

```
 [BindProperty]
    public List<Thread> Threads { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Tester> Testers { get; set; }
    public int ThreadsCounter { get; set;  }
    public int TestersCounter { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
        Threads = db.GetThreads();
        ThreadsCounter = Threads.Count;

        Testers = db.GetTesters();
        TestersCounter = Testers.Count;
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
        db.UpdateThread(Threads);
    }
```

Option 1 (html select):

```
<div>
        <table class="thread-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Test name</th>
                    <th>Data check tester</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.ThreadsCounter; i++)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td>@Model.Threads[i].Id</td>
                        <td>@Model.Threads[i].ThreadNumber</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="dataTester-@i">
                                @if (Model.Threads[i].DataCheckTesterId == 0)
                                {
                                    <option>--select--</option>
                                }
                                @for (int j = 0; j < @Model.TestersCounter; j++)
                                {
                                    if (Model.Testers[j].Id == Model.Threads[i].DataCheckTesterId)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@Model.Testers[j].TesterName" selected>@Model.Testers[j].TesterName</option>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <option value="@Model.Testers[j].TesterName">@Model.Testers[j].TesterName</option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

When use the drop-down to change the tester and i submit the form the value that is passed to Model.Threads[i].DataCheckTesterId (the tester's id) doesn't change. So if i want to change Tester1 to Tester2, i still pass the ID=1 and there is no change.

Option 2 (Html.DropDownList) - i know that this is the way to go, but the result is even worse so far:

```
<div>
<form method="post">
    <table class="thread-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Test name</th>
                <th>Data check tester</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var thread in Model.Threads)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Threads.Index" value="@thread.Id" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="Threads[@thread.Id].Id" value="@thread.Id" />
                        @thread.Id
                    </td>
                    <td>@thread.ThreadNumber</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Threads[@thread.DataCheckTesterId].Id" value="@thread.DataCheckTesterId" />
                        @Html.DropDownList("TestersList", new SelectList(Model.Testers, "Id", "TesterName", thread.DataCheckTesterId), "Select")
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button>Update</button>
</form>
```

When i change the tester and submit, the value that is passed as Id = 0.

I've got all confused what is going on here but i suspect that this is caused by 2 properties (tests and testers) interfering with each other. I'd really appreciate a push in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes, you can refer to the below codes:

Model:

```
public class Thread
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ThreadName { get; set; }
    public int DataCheckTesterId { get; set; }
}

public class Tester
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TesterName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    var count = 0;
}

<form method="post">
    <table class="thread-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Test name</th>
                <th>Data check tester</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var thread in Model.Threads)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Threads[@count].Id" value="@thread.Id" />
                        @thread.Id
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Threads[@count].ThreadName" value="@thread.ThreadName" />
                        @thread.ThreadName
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("Threads[" + count + "].DataCheckTesterId", new SelectList(Model.Testers, "Id", "TesterName", thread.DataCheckTesterId), "Select")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                count++;
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button>Update</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<Thread> Threads { get; set; }
[BindProperty]
public List<Tester> Testers { get; set; }
public int ThreadsCounter { get; set; }
public int TestersCounter { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{

    Threads = new List<Thread>
    {
        new Thread{ Id = 1, ThreadName = "Tester1", DataCheckTesterId = 0},
        new Thread{ Id = 2, ThreadName = "Tester2", DataCheckTesterId = 0},
        new Thread{ Id = 3, ThreadName = "Tester3", DataCheckTesterId = 0},
    };

    Testers = new List<Tester>
    {
        new Tester{ Id = 1, TesterName = "AA"},
        new Tester{ Id = 2, TesterName = "BB"},
        new Tester{ Id = 3, TesterName = "CC"},
    };
}

public void OnPost()
{

}
```

Result:

[image]